# How to debug QWebView's failure to load a web page?

Tags: qtwebkit, qwebview

I use QWebView to load a page, then I only keep reloading it with `reload()`slot. `loadFinished(bool)` signal often undicates false. I also use QwebView's network access manager's `finished` signal to get http response code - it's set to 0. 
The same page loads fine with all browsers, no matter how fast I try to relaod it in browser. How to debug this problem, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to get the reply's error code and error message, like this:

```
class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._request_finished)

        self.web_page = QWebPage()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network_manager)

        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)

    def _request_finished(self, reply):
        print reply.error()
        print reply.errorString()
```

Comment: At which point are you hitting the reload function, after a loadFinished is emitted, or just continuously, no matter the page is loaded or not ? If that's the case, that should be the reason why you got an OperationCanceledError.

Comment: I got it, thanks! I'm reloading the page on timer and I don't check whether previous load has completed or not.